# $wpdb->posts not being accepted by Wordpress Pugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Hope you all have been doing great...

I am here today to look for an answer to my issue...

I created a plugin and activated it, it does not create a table etc just simple php script.

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: F
Plugin URI: h
Description: T
Author: D
Author URI: h
*/

$server = "localhost";
$user = "admin";
$password = "";
$db = "wordpress";

$con = mysql_connect($server,$user,$password); 

if (!$con) {
    die("database connection error");
} else 

{

    mysql_select_db($db, $con);

    $results = mysql_query("SELECT ID, post_title FROM wp_posts "

    . "WHERE "

    . "post_status = 'publish' "
    );

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results))
    {
        echo $row['post_title'];
    }

}
```

the autocomplete code is as below

```
    $("#imageSearch").autocomplete("<?php echo bloginfo('wpurl')."/wp-content/plugins/foxycomplete/"; ?>foxycomplete.php", {
dataType: "json",
    parse: function(data) {
        return $.map(data, function(row) {
            return {
            data: row,
            value: row.title,
            result: $("#imageSearch").val()
            }
        });
    }

}).result(function(e, item) {
    location.href = link(item);
    });
});
```

this is working but I am pretty sure that this is not the right way. I am not able to use the wp functions is the plugin script and also this seems unsafe and prone to hacking...

could anyone please help how I can get a php file to feed the autocomplete that can access wop functions and is safe?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as a **Plugin Page**. The code above should probably be wrapped in a function and called from somewhere in a WordPress context, or it should be used in an action or a filter.

Comment: I do not know how to do that. I have updated the question to show you what I am exactly doing now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing the plugin page directly rather than from within Wordpress, the problem might be that the $wpdb is not being initialized.  This is done in the WordPress header, which is normally included on the page if you are inside of a Wordpress template.  Try including wp-blog-header.php in your script with something like this:

```
include_once(‘wp-blog-header.php’);
```

Comment: doesnt work - I have updated the question to a better understanding... could you please help!